# React App only re-renders on first state change and changes are not visible for second change even though the change is successful

Tags: reactjs

I am tryin to implement dark mode in a React app. I have given a toggle on my child component to change the theme to dark mode. So lets say if we start with dark mode and we click on toggle then theme changes to light one. Now, if toggle a second time, the theme does not change but the state value does change.

As I understand, if a state changes component should re-render and it does so but only once!

Please let me know what is going wrong.

```
App.js
------
import themes from '../theme';
import Container from '../common/container';

const App = function(props) {

 const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = React.useState(true);

 const changeTheme = function(){
  console.log('Dark Mode is ' + darkMode + ', Setting it to ' + !darkMode)
  setDarkMode(!darkMode)
 }
 
 return (
  <Router>
    <ThemeProvider theme={ darkMode ? themes.darkTheme : themes.lightTheme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container darkMode={darkMode} changeTheme={changeTheme}>
        </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </Router>
 );
}
```

As you can see the App component has state darkMode and its toggle is passed to the child component Container.

```
Container.js
------------

const Container = function(props) {
 return (
  <Box>
    <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
            .
            .
          <IconButton color="primary" onClick={(event) => props.changeTheme()}>{ props.darkMode ?
          <Brightness4Icon /> : <BrightnessHighIcon /> }</IconButton>

           <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    <Box>
      {props.children}
    </Box>
  </Box>
 )
}
```

So in Container component, if you click on IconButton, the changeTheme funtion of App Component will be called.

Now, the result of this code is - I am able to change the theme only on first click be it dark mode first or light mode first. The Second and further clicks does not change the theme.

Also, as you have noticed I have a log statement in changeTheme. PF the attached console screenshot.
[image]

So, as per my understanding App should re-render if darkMode changes. But is only does for the first time.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure but could you try to use arrow function here? ' const changeTheme = function(){'

Comment: Also i found here https://medium.com/heuristics/react-dark-mode-switch-in-material-ui-dashboard-82fcf1cded66 that they recreate Material Theme when they change theme

Comment: Creating MuiTheme every time works! Its the same concept as to use a callback to update inner objects/keys of a state because the object remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what is wrong with your code, but if you are using `Context` there is no need to pass darkMode to `Container`.

I made a quick working example off of your code, modify it to fit your needs.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

const ThemeContext = React.createContext("light");

function App() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = React.useState(true);

  const changeTheme = function(){
    console.log('Dark Mode is ' + darkMode + ', Setting it to ' + !darkMode)
    setDarkMode(!darkMode)
 }  

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={darkMode ? "dark" : "light"}>
      <Container changeTheme={changeTheme}/>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}

function Container({changeTheme}) {
  const theme = React.useContext(ThemeContext);

  return <React.Fragment>
    {theme}

    <button onClick={changeTheme}>Toggle Theme</button>
  </React.Fragment>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

As you can see, in the `Container` you can use `useContext` to get the theme value, there is no need to pass it as a property, that's the whole point of contexts.

You can test the code above in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-flzv6)

If this is unclear, you can read more about the `useContext` hook in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext). There is also an example of theme context implementation.

Comment: I am passing the darkMode to Container just to render proper Icon. Even in my code the state is changing as in your example but the re-render doesn't happen. Thanks for pointing out the usage of context.

Comment: I will try to implement using context, as I think this would be cleaner. As of now, creating MuiTheme object everytime works.